# How to expand ribbon options?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon, user-experience

Kinda silly question but I can't find the answer. How do I expand these options?
[image]

Comment: The text/arrow below each icon expands the submenu.

Comment: No, I need to be permanent. There is another view for it

Comment: Where have you added the list/library view?

Comment: Ah, i see. Edit the webpart and change the "Toolbar Type" to "Show Toolbar". This will make it always visible.

Comment: They won't be compacted like that?

Comment: I want a view like this. https://imgur.com/a/1d5hQkm

Comment: So, you wan't it to be expanded by default? Guess you could trigger it with some javascript on page load. On a single list or library?

Comment: Check if your chrome Zoom level is less than normal(100%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **maximize** the window of browser.

It will automatically collapse some options to make it look friendly if you change the browser window to a small size.

Comment: Thank you. It was 90% zoomed in so that was the problem.